# Text is cut if using maxLines, textAppearanceBody1 and gravity end

Tags: android

[image]

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I try to apply Material design so I use `textAppearanceBody1`. However, after I use `textAppearanceBody1` with `maxLines`, some text is cut off. In the above image, you can see the letters **"text of"** is **cut off**.
Is there any way to make `textAppearanceBody1` work with `maxLines` without above issue?

**UPDATE**
I think the problem may come from `letterSpacing`. Currently, the default `letterSpacing` from `textAppearanceBody1` is `0.03125`.

If I set `android:letterSpacing="0"`, this issue **won't happened**. But it still not a good way.

Comment: This is weird. Is it happening on running on real device

Comment: yes, it happened on both preview and device, very easy to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="end"
android:maxLines="2"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I think the width of `TextView` is not the reason, and sometime, we still need to fixed the width of `TextView`. I found a new thing, please check my update in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that i understand what are you trying to achieve but i guess that changing the width from 280dp to "wrap_content" or "match_parent" may resolve the issue.

Comment: still same issue when using `match_parent` . `280dp` is just a demo value but in some case we still need a fixed width for `TextView`

Comment: I forgot to mention that for the match parent to work, you need to specify the right constraint to the right of the parent view. Did you try the wrap_content?

Comment: I can not use wrap_content because I want to set the maxLines to 2

Answer (score 0):

You specified width of 280dp. and max lines of 2. So, that is expected behavior. The text will try to fit in the area available and will get cut if it is larger.

So, either you increase the width or just create constraints to the left and right of Parent, and set TextView width=0dp.

But, if you increase the number of characters in your text, even more, the problem will arise again.

Comment: this is why I specify ellipsize, when there is more text, I want to display ... in the end. beside that, I have update my question with a new clue

Comment: @Linh Try this: android:singleLine="false" maybe?

Comment: just try, it not work, also singleLine is deprecated